# How to make a snapshot from hbase to hive quickly?

Tags: hive, hbase

My company has a hbase cluster of about 30 machines. Every morning I will start a spark/mr task to synchronous data from hbase to hive for writing SQL to make analysing.

The question is: a table in hbase is becoming bigger and bigger, it has more than 1k columns. Now its size is about 15 TB. I want to copy all data to hbase, with less time. Scan takes hours, is there any other way?

Comment: do you use the hbase  [snapshot functionality](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#ops.snapshots)?